# changing language only once

Tags: android, localization

In my application I am trying change language by clicking buttons (English/Italian). I choose default locale English. When opens activity and I press Italian button it changed but after that I couldn't choose English. In other word language changed only one time. What I did wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends DefaultActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    String LOCALE_ITALIAN = "it";
    String LOCALE_ENGLISH = "en";
    Locale mLocale;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mLocale = new Locale(LOCALE_ENGLISH);
        Locale.setDefault(mLocale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = mLocale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        findButton(R.id.english).setOnClickListener(this);
        findButton(R.id.italian).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.english:
                mLocale = new Locale(LOCALE_ENGLISH);
                Locale.setDefault(mLocale);
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                config.locale = mLocale;
                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                MainActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.main);

                break;
            case R.id.italian:
                mLocale = new Locale(LOCALE_ITALIAN);
                Locale.setDefault(mLocale);
                Configuration config1 = new Configuration();
                config1.locale = mLocale;
                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config1,
                        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                MainActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.main);

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there an exception thrown at all when you try to go back to english?

Comment: There is no any exception

Comment: Does it work reversal? ie, setting default as Italian and change to English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I run your code and found solution. When you update your view by calling setContentView you have to call again buttons onclick. I'm sure it will work.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.english:
                mLocale = new Locale(LOCALE_ENGLISH);
                Locale.setDefault(mLocale);
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                config.locale = mLocale;
                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                NonOrangeUserActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.non_orange_user);
                findButton(R.id.english).setOnClickListener(this);
                findButton(R.id.italian).setOnClickListener(this);

                break;
            case R.id.italian:
                mLocale = new Locale(LOCALE_ITALIAN);
                Locale.setDefault(mLocale);
                Configuration config1 = new Configuration();
                config1.locale = mLocale;
                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config1,
                        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                NonOrangeUserActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.non_orange_user);
                findButton(R.id.english).setOnClickListener(this);
                findButton(R.id.italian).setOnClickListener(this);

                break;
        }
    }
```